# ASP.NET Web service - restrict methods to HttpGet or HttpPost

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http-post, asmx, http-get

I'm trying to make a web service that would respond to HttpGet and HttpPost requests differently.

I have enabled HttpGet with this:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

And I created 2 functions, one that should be fired for HttpPost request and the other - on HttpGet:

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("HelloWorld")]
public string HelloWorldPost()
{
    return "Hello POST World";
}

[WebMethod]
[HttpGet]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello GET World";
}
```

However it seems that HttpGet, HttpPost and ActionName get ignored completely. All requests to HelloWorld (post or get) fire the second function. Do I need to do this some other way? I also tried to limit the functions with this:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
```

But that also made no difference.

Comment: Are you using asp.net webapi?

Comment: I guess not... I'm using "ASP.NET Web Service Application" project type from Visual Studio (.NET framework 3.5). I have not downloaded any additional libs or apis.

Comment: HttpPostAttribute is from MVC and exists only in .NET 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: You are using the ancient ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Web Service Application behave differently than ASP.NET MVC, which is along the lines of your expectations. In your code, both HttpGet/HttpPost and ActionName attributes belong to MVC as noted by Amiram Korach. Those attributes are ignored when hosted as a web service application.

"Routing" in web service application is based on the method name (HelloWorldPost and HelloWorld) and not based on HTTP VERB.

To trigger the POST flow, you have to invoke `HelloWorldPost` (service.asmx/HelloWorldPost)

Comment: Thank you. You pretty much confirmed what I suspected - that I have mixed up 2 different things. I rewrote the whole thing using WCF Service and it is working correctly for me now :)

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea.

For starters, your web.config file for yor web service will look like this:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
     <add name="HttpGet"/>
     <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Next, regardless of the form method you use, you call a web method x.

```
[WebMethod]
public string X()
{
  //so, you detect which method is invoked by using 
  // HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod
  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST") {
    //do something now you know it is post method
  }
  else {
    //now, it should be get method and you do something different
  }
//end of web method
}
```

My main point is that you check `HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod` and depending on which method is used, you invoke different methods.